# I'd rather something do something else -- grammar pattern

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, semi-modals

Example (audio version: http://tindeck.com/listen/wtoo):

> You may not have ever come across this before. For example, my food order ID, I want it to be an Autonumber data type because I don't care what the number is. I want it to be a number. But **I'd rather Access just take care of** making sure that my food order IDs are unique.

Could you please explain to me how this grammar pattern works?

Comment: The past form "took care" is probably more common. (For example, see http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner.) I think whether using the present subjective is possible (as the speaker did) is quite interesting. (It makes me think of something like "I wish he be here" or "I wish she take care of it".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phew, what an example...

Let's use a shorter example with less tech speak.

> - I'd rather my Mom cook dinner tonight. **or**
> - I'd rather my Mom cooked dinner tonight.

Pattern:
Subject 1 - would/'d rather - subject 2 - verb - ....

This is a slightly more complex pattern that the would rather - phrases with the *same* subject (subject - would/'d rather - verb in infinitive/subjunctive); e.g. I'd rather have a cookie (...than ice cream).

This pattern is used to express a preference, but note that the alternative is not always stated expicitly. Quite often, it has to be inferred from the context.

Please note:

- In AE, *both present subjunctive and past subjunctive* are gramatically correct. 
  Hint for learners: The present subjunctive seems quite similar to the simple present. It can best be recognized by the "missing +s" in 3rd person singular. (-> *...Access **take** care of...*) The past forms are identical. Only exception: The verb "be" has two distict subjunctive forms: *be* (present) and *were* (past).
- In BE, for two different subjects:
  The verb in *simple past* is used to talk about events *in the present or the future*. 
   For *past* events, you need to use *past perfect*.
  [See more details: Cambridge University](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner)

Therefore, your original example could also be:

> But I'd rather Access just **took** care of making sure that my food order IDs are unique.

Comment: But the OP's example has a verb in the plain form *take* not *took* :)

Comment: *Would rather* can take backshifted verb forms as you've used, or it can take verbs in the plain form, as in the OP's example. As you point out the Op's example is a bit of a mouthful!

Comment: Well you could have a look [here](http://www.infosquares.com/eslblog/blog_04032008.html)

Comment: If you're saying that AE can't use past perfect for past events, that's incorrect.

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm not. Im referring to tense in OP's example only. For more detaiils, I've given the link - I don't want to "blow up" my answer into a grammar lesson ;-)

Comment: Actually, in AmE, I think it's not the simple present but the present subjunctive that is used (as in the OP's quote) — Google books has one hit for *"would rather he goes"* and quite a few for *"would rather he go"*. This also seems to be a relatively new development grammatically — formerly, AmE would have been the same as BrE. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rather+he+go+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crather%20he%20go%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Stephie: much better.

Answer (score 1):

In:

> I want it to be a number. But I'd rather Access just **take** care of making sure that my food order IDs are unique.

using *take* in the present tense is OK, because at such time (if it happens) that Access performs such an action ( making sure that my food order IDs are unique) it will be in the present time.

Another example:

> I would rather you **leave** me alone tonight.

Borrowing from the example from @Stephie:

> I'd rather my Mom **cook** dinner tonight.

is also OK.

However, I think past tense is often used, but I don't think that is necessarily correct.

(AmE disclaimer)

Comment: Past tense is *required* in British English for two different subjects.

Comment: @Stephie OK, I added the necessary disclaimer. The question has no region specific tag so I can only guess what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> You may not have ever come across this before. For example, my food
>   order ID, I want it to be an Autonumber data type because I don't care
>   what the number is. I want it to be a number. But I'd rather Access
>   just take care of making sure that my food order IDs are unique.

This passage is very colloquial, a transcript of an oral presentation, perhaps. The publisher of this text may have no editors on staff.

> You may not have ever come across this before.

**You may not have seen this before.**

> For example, my food order ID, I want it to be...

**... ID, which I want to be an Autonumber.**

> I want it to be a number. But I'd rather Access just take care of making sure that my food order IDs are unique.

Normally, "I'd rather" implies a *choice*, not merely a wish. And "but" usually involves a contrast or a conflict or an exception.  But there is no choice here, and there is no conflict.

**I want the ID to be a number, and I want Access to make sure that my IDs are unique.**