# would rather eat or ate?

Tags: verbs

*Would rather (but not would prefer to) is also followed by a past tense when we want to involve other people in the action, even though it has a present or future meaning. Study the following:*

*a.Shall we go out for dinner tonight? ~ No, I'd rather we ate at home, if you don't mind.*

b.**My rephrased:  Shall we go out for dinner tonight? ~ No, I'd rather we eat at home, if you don't mind.**

I have extracted the italic parts from a grammar site, but would you tell me if the bold part is correct, too? If so, what is the difference between a. and b. semantically?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/id-rather-something-do-something-else-grammar-pattern/43563#43563 there, we discussed the use of "rather" with subjunctive or simple past - basically, its AE vs BE.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you asked about a special use of ***would rather***.
Without trying to explain the grammar point on my own, I will let you read what the author says about this special usage.

[image]

Comment: Problem here: true for BE, AE actively uses subjunctive, which is easily confused with simple present.